# Reading properties from an XML file using Input Stream?

Tags: java, xml, properties, static, inputstream

Currently within my `Java` Application I have the following `Class` that I use in order to retrieve values from my `properties` file (application.properties):

```
public class MyProperties {
    private static Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
    static {
        try {

            java.io.InputStream in= MyProperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
            defaultProps.load(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static String getProperty(String key) {
        return defaultProps.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

An example of instantiating an `int` using the `MyProperties` class:

```
int maxNumberOfPeople = Integer.parseInt(MyProperties.getProperty("maximumPeople"));
```

I would like to change this class in order to read an `XML` properties file rather than e.g. application.Properties.

How can I do so, and still keep the ability to still instantiate values using the MyProperties class?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072602/java-properties-in-xml.html

Comment: flagged the question as 'too broad'. There are different ways to do this as well (opinion based). Please try something and if it doesn't work, post that code and the error you are facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML-java.io.InputStream-) for the `Properties.loadFromXML(...)` method.

Method summary:

> Loads all of the properties represented by the XML document on the specified input stream into this properties table.

The `Properties` javadoc includes the DTD for the XML document (file).

---

It would be better to write your loader using a try-with-resources like this:

```
try (java.io.InputStream in = MyProperties.class.getClassLoader().
            getResourceAsStream("application.properties")) {
    // load properties
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also, it is a bad idea to catch and squash exceptions like that.

1. Don't catch `Exception`.
2. If the properties failed to load, you most likely want the application to "bail out".

Finally, you probably shouldn't load the properties in a static initializer, because that leaves you with no clean way to deal with any exceptions that might arise.